# Python regex confused by brackets ([])?

Tags: python, regex

Is python confused, or is the programmer?

I've got a lot of lines of this:

```
some_dict[0x2a] = blah
some_dict[0xab] = blah, blah
```

What I'd like to do is to convert the hex codes into all uppercase to look like this:

```
some_dict[0x2A] = blah
some_dict[0xAB] = blah, blah
```

So I decided to call in the regular expressions.  Normally, I'd just do this using my editor's regexps (xemacs), but the need to convert to uppercase pushes one into Lisp.  ....ok... how about Python?

So I whip together a short script which doesn't work.  I've condensed the code into this example, which doesn't work either.  It looks to me like Python's regexps are getting confused by the brackets in the code.  Is it me or Python?

```
import fileinput
import sys
import re


this = "0x2a"
that = "[0x2b]"

for line in [this, that]:
    found = re.match("0x([0-9,a-f]{2})", line)

    if found:
        print("Found: %s" % found.group(0))
```

(I'm using the () grouping constructs so I don't capitalize the 'x' in '0x'.)

This example only prints the 0x2a value, not the 0x2b.  Is this correct behavior?

I can easily work around this by changing the match expression to:

```
    found = re.match("\[0x([0-9,a-f]{2}\])", line)
```

but I'm just wondering if someone can give me some insight into what's going on here.

Running Python 2.6.2 on Linux.

Comment: Are you aware that `[` and `]` have special meanings in a regex?  They're not *just* characters?  What regex documentation are you reading?  I don't see any way around your `'\\[...\\]` version.  What problem do you have?

Comment: You dont need the , in the character class `[0-9a-b]` will work fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`re.match` matches from the *start* of the string.  Use `re.search` instead to "match the first occurrence anywhere in the string".  The key bit about this in the docs is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match).

Comment: Ah, so simple.  Dirty words!  Thanks, Alex.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need the comma within the brackets. i.e.:

```
found = re.match("0x([0-9,a-f]{2})", line)
```

tells python to look for commas which it might be mistakenly matching. I think you want

```
found = re.match("0x([0-9a-f]{2})", line)
```

Comment: This should be a comment, since its not answering the question.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to leave comments yet, sorry.

Comment: ahh ok, no problem. sorry myself :D

Answer (score 4):

You're using a partial pattern, so you can't use `re.match`, which expects to match the entire input string. You need to use `re.search`, which can perform partial matches.

```
>>> that = "[0x2b]"
>>> m = re.search("0x([0-9,a-f]{2})", that)
>>> m.group()
'0x2b'
```

Comment: re.match does NOT expect to match the entire input string. It attempts a match at the beginning of the string. If you want to match the entire string, you need to append `r"\Z"` (*NOT* `"$"`) to the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to change

```
found = re.match("0x([0-9,a-f]{2})", line)
```

to

```
found = re.search("0x([0-9,a-f]{2})", line)
```

**re.match** will match *only from the beginning of the string*, which fails in the "[0x2b]" case.

**re.search** will match *anywhere in the string*, and thus ignore the leading "[" in the "[0x2b]" case.

See [search() vs. match()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match) for details.

Comment: re.match does NOT expect to match the entire input string. It attempts a match at the beginning of the string. If you want to match the entire string, you need to append r"\Z" (NOT "$") to the pattern.

Comment: True, updated accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `re.search`. [This explains why.](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching)

Answer (score 1):

If you use re.sub, and pass a callable as the replacement string, it will also do the uppercasing for you:

```
>>> that = 'some_dict[0x2a] = blah'
>>> m = re.sub("0x([0-9,a-f]{2})", lambda x: "0x"+x.group(1).upper(), that)
>>> m
'some_dict[0x2A] = blah'
```